# Disable processing validation annotations in springdoc

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc, jakarta-validation

I want to remove parameter "minimum" from autogenerated swagger documentation

I use the springdoc library to automatically generate swagger documentation

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have this method in one of the controllers

```java
@GetMapping("page")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
List<RecordInfoDto> getPage(@RequestParam("size")
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 1, message = "size must be more than 0") 
                            int size,
                            @RequestParam("number")
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 0, message = "number must be non-negative")
                            int number);
```

The following documentation is generated for this method

```json
"/page": {
    "get": {
    ...
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "size",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "minimum": 1,
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "number",
            "in": "query",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "minimum": 0,
              "type": "integer",
              "format": "int32"
            }
          }
        ],
     ...
```

I want the same swagger documentation, only without the "minimum" parameter in the "schema" section

I tried to explicitly specify scheme using the io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.annotation.Scheme, but it didn't help, in whatever order I put the annotations

```java
@GetMapping("page")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
List<RecordInfoDto> getPage(@RequestParam("size")
                            @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema(minimum = "100")
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 1, message = "size must be more than 0")
                            int size,
                            @RequestParam("number")
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 0, message = "number must be non-negative")
                            int number);
```

The documentation still had "minimum": 1 for parameter size

I tried using io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter, but it didn't help either

```java
@GetMapping("page")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
List<RecordInfoDto> getPage(@RequestParam("size")
                            @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter(name = "size",
                                    required = true,
                                    in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
                                    schema = @Schema(minimum = "100"))
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 1, message = "size must be more than 0")
                            int size,
                            @RequestParam("number")
                            @jakarta.validation.constraints.Min(value = 0, message = "number must be non-negative")
                            int number);
```

At the same time, if I remove the annotation jakarta.validation.constraints.Min, the documentation is generated according to the annotations and the minimum becomes 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to **make** the Open API specification **lie**.

As you said in the comment, you "don't want to remove the `@Min` annotation, because it is required for **real validation**", on other side you want to hide this validation constraint in the generated Open API specification.

Your requirement is contradictory and you should not be surprised that it is not possible.

The purpose of the documentation is to specify the **contract** of your API. If your API validates minimum value, it is a part of its contract. And the purpose of a machine readable documentation (Open API) is among other to automatically prevent the clients to send an invalid request.

Having `@Schema(minimum="100")` **and** `@Min(value=1)` is schizophrenic.

The validation is **part of the contract** and it *should* be in the Open API specification. If a part of the contract is that the minimum value is 1, you don't have to specify anything else. It is *obvious* (part of a more general contract of any web service) that the client will receive `400` and *some* meaningful error message. I never recommend to *promise* any exact error message in the contract.

You may also add to the whole `RestController` class or to every single method *something like* this:

```java
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", 
    content = @Content(
        mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        schema = @Schema(implementation = MyError.class),
        examples = @ExampleObject(value = "{\"code\": \"INVALID_INPUT\", \"message\": \"Currency USD not supported\" }")
    )
)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "403",
    content = @Content(
        mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        schema = @Schema(implementation = MyError.class),
        examples = @ExampleObject(value = "{\"code\": \"FORBIDDEN\", \"message\": \"Forbidden access to something\" }")
    )
)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", 
    content = @Content(
        mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        schema = @Schema(implementation = MyError.class),
        examples = @ExampleObject(value = "{\"code\": \"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND\", \"message\": \"User not found\" }")
    )
)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "500",
    content = @Content(
        mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
        schema = @Schema(implementation = MyError.class),
        examples = @ExampleObject(value = "{\"code\": \"EXTERNAL_API_CALL_ERROR\", \"message\": \"Central register API not available\" }")))
```

Comment: I use the swagger documentation to generate a swagger ui based on it. And in my case, this is only necessary so that the user can test the service in a convenient format. Maybe it's not quite the right use, but that's what I need. And I want the user to see in case of an incorrect request that the service will actually return. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any way how to use a screwdriver to slice the bread? Yes, there probably is, but it's much better to use it to tighten the screws :) Anyway, see my edit.